# Oracle DBMS Registry Schema - Does anyone know how to make dbms registry call with BLOB shcemadoc?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

The below stored procedure gives error and I don't find any solution to solve this issue to make BLOB field acceptable for the register schema. Please let me know what wrong in this statement.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE xsdUpload2(
    p_schemaURL IN VARCHAR2 ,
    p_schemaDoc IN BLOB )

IS
  schemaURL varchar2;
  schemaDoc BLOB;

BEGIN
    schemaURL := p_schemaURL; 
    schemaDoc := p_schemaDoc;
    dbms_xmlschema.registerSchema(schemaURL, schemaDoc , nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8')) , local => true , genTypes => true, genbean => false, genTables => True );
```

> **Error:** *Error(19,86): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "," when expecting one of the following:     := . ( % ;*

Comment: I gues it's a typo check *('AL32UTF8')) , local*

Answer (score 2):

It is the extra paranthesis at the end of `nls_charset_id` here -

```
dbms_xmlschema.registerSchema(schemaURL, schemaDoc , nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8'))
```

This makes the `registerSchema` function call end and hence error out on the other parameters.

Use an IDE like Toad or SQL Developer that can catch these errors while you write them.

Comment: Thanks and finally solved the stored procedure and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

This stored procedure works for me. Before I was missing BEGIN and END after declaration. It was causing all the problem.

`create or replace 
PROCEDURE xsdUpload2(
    p_schemaURL IN VARCHAR2,
    p_schemaDoc IN BLOB,
    v_response OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
  DECLARE
    schemaXML BLOB := p_schemaDoc;
  BEGIN
    dbms_xmlschema.registerschema(schemaurl => p_schemaURL, schemadoc => schemaXML, local => true , genTypes => true, genbean => false, genTables => true);
    v_response :='SUCCESS';
    COMMIT;
  EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    v_response := 'ERROR: Either this schema already exists (or) error occured while executing registerschema . Verify input parameter passed to stored procedure';
  END;
END;`